# How to convert iPhone app to universal in xcode4, if I previously converted, but deleted MainWindow-iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4

I have iPhone app and I converted it in xcode4 to universal app, and it worked fine, but after that I deleted MainWindow-iPad and return to iPhone app only. Now I need to make my app universal again, I clicked in Xcode4 "Devices-Universal", but XCode don't create MainWindow-iPad and don't ask me "Transition to universal target" so when I'm building and running in iPad simulator app crashes. How can I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own mainwindow-ipad nib file and set it as main nib file for the iPad platform in your info.plist

Comment: I did that, app loads in iPad simulator with white screen, without any controls

Comment: **Solution:**

1.I manually added MainWindow-iPad.xib, changed File's Owner class to UIApplication. 

2.Add object to MainWindow-iPad.xib using IB and set class to YourAppDelegate.

3.Connect using IBOutlet File's Owner and YourAppDelegate "delegate".

4.Set in XCode "iPad Deployment Info - Main Interface - MainWindow-iPad".

Thats all.